# Angular HttpClientModule errors

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on my first Angular app and dealing with the HttpClientModule in my component and getting errors.

following the docs [Angular -HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) I installed the HttpClientModule in the app.module.ts as instructed, then in my emails.component.ts I have the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emails',
  templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emails.component.scss'],
  results: string[]
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }

}
```

which is giving me the following error in my console:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(7,3): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; results: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'results' does not exist in type 'Component'.
src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(7,12): error TS2693: 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(7,19): error TS1109: Expression expected.
src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(12,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'HttpClient'.
src/app/components/emails/emails.component.ts(16,12): error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'EmailsComponent'.
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmailsComponent } from './components/emails/emails.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Show me your `app.module.ts`, also you cannot have `results: string[]` in the `@Component` annotation because it doesn't know

Comment: That's right, you never define the field `results` within `EmailsComponent`, you try to pass it as an argument to the `@Component` decorator. Also, you try to use `HttpClient` without actually importing it. This is nothing to do with the `HttpClientModule`, you've simply put the field definition in the wrong place and failed to import the things you're trying to use. I'd strongly recommend you run through some structured tutorial materials, e.g. https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @MikeTung I added code for my app.module.ts

Comment: @MikeTung this isn't related to the module definition, either; it's not getting as far as checking in the module for the dependency because *the `HttpClient` token doesn't exist in that file*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app module you forgot to provide.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmailsComponent } from './components/emails/emails.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpClient],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emails',
  templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emails.component.scss']
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {
  results: string[]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: No, the `HttpClientModule` defines the `HttpClient` as a provider. Also you don't actually import it.

Answer (score 1):

you're component should be: 
first you need to import `HttpClient`

second `results: string[]` should be inside the `class` not at decoration `component` exactly as I did here :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emails',
  templateUrl: './emails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emails.component.scss']
})

export class EmailsComponent implements OnInit {

results: string[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/email_list.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }

}
```

Please read the description carefully, they explaining you need to load `HttpClient`.